# Where can I find complete set of mapnik/mapbox fonts?

Tags: mapbox, mapnik, font

I think there is something I am missing here.  Many of Mapbox Products are dependent on font types I am not finding available in the resources.

For example, mapbox-studio-outdoors.tm2, relies on 'Arial Unicode MS Regular'. The mapnik fonts located at C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib\mapnik\fonts only contains 'Deja Vu-sans' by default.

From Mapbox [github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-default-fonts) I can find a list of additional fontsets including opensans, crimson, source-sans-pro and more... But no 'Arial...' anything?

Where should I be looking for adding additional fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Mapbox, see https://www.mapbox.com/help/add-custom-fonts/

I assume you have access to that font if you are registered at Mapbox.

These fonts are copyrighted by Microsoft. According to https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081,  `Arial Unicode MS Regular` is shipped with many Microsoft products, but not freely available elsewhere.

You can read here how to integrate any font in Mapnik:

https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UsingCustomFonts

http://weait.com/content/add-fonts-your-openstreetmap-server

Comment: Thank you Andre for this. Your details have helped me ensure a complete and proper installation of mapnik.  Re: mapbox I can see the available fonts and and an option to upload new fonts but nothing on downloading. Where can I obtain missing fonts for local use on cmd line tools such as [tilelive/tessera](https://github.com/mojodna/tessera)?

Comment: I guess the local use is not intended. They assume you have registered and have therefore access to the online fonts.